# What kind of Schema.org tags to use for several links groups?

Tags: schema.org

I am trying to correctly mark several blocks containing links to articles. Each block contains links to publications depending on the category. There are several blocks of this type on the site. The site is not a blog but a portal, so tags associated with [`Blog`](https://schema.org/Blog) are not appropriate (unless I'm wrong). Which tags should I use?

I tried with [`ItemList`](https://schema.org/ItemList) → [`itemListElement`](https://schema.org/itemListElement) → [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article). Everything works fine for a single list. In the case of subsequent lists, I receive a message that the `ItemList` tag can not appear several times on the page. Any ideas how to approach it?

Comment: Do you expect to get a specific rich result in Google Search (if yes, which one?), or do you just want to provide structured data -- no matter which consumer makes use of it?

Comment: Hi @unor. I just want to provide structural data but in such a way that the whole code would be validated in the structural data testing tool

Comment: The SDTT is biased towards validating for Googles rich snippet requirements. So warnings and errors there may not actually be invalid schema.org. Saying that, complying with what Google wants will improve your chances of complying with what most systems support. Could you do an ItemList of Item Lists?